# Proving the convergence of $\int e^{x^2/2} dF_{1,2}(x)$ in Cramers proof of the

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

In Cramer 1936 the proof of the Cramer decomposition theorem contains proving the following integrals are finite
$$\int e^{x^2/2} dF_{1}(x),  \quad \int e^{x^2/2} dF_{2}(x)$$
to later use in finding a bound for the characteristic functions.

We are solving the integral equation
$$\int F_1(x-t)F_2(dt)=\Phi(x),\quad \Phi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^x e^{-t^2/2} dt.$$

The proof goes as follows:

Since the first moment of $F_2$ is $0$ there exists a $\lambda >0$ so that $F_2(-\lambda)>0$. For all $x<0$:
\begin{align}\Phi(x-\lambda)&=\int F_1(x-\lambda-t)F_2(dt) \\ &\geq\int_{-\infty}^{-\lambda} F_1(x-\lambda-t)F_2(dt) \\ 
&\rm \color{red}{\geq F_1(x)F_2(-\lambda)}
\end{align}
And therefore
$$ F_1(x)\leq \frac{\Phi(x-\lambda)}{F_2(-\lambda)}<Ae^{-\frac{x^2}{2}+\lambda x}$$
Where $A$ is independent of $x$.
Analogue for $x>0$:
$$1-F_1(x)<Be^{-\frac{x^2}{2}-\mu x}$$
Where $B$ and $\mu$ are positive numbers independent of $x$.

I don't understand how the inequality in red follows.
How did this show the integral is finite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, he is simply using monotonicity and positivity of distribution functions and the definition itself of distribution function: indeed the argument $x-\lambda-t$ attains it minimum on $[-\lambda,-\infty)$ at $-\lambda$ and thus by monotonicity of the distribution
$$F_1(x-\lambda-t)\geq F_1(x-\lambda-(-\lambda))=F_1(x)\geq 0.$$
Now we simply have
$$\int_{-\infty}^{-\lambda}F_1(x-\lambda-t)\ F_2(dt)\geq F_1(x)\int_{-\infty}^{-\lambda}F_2(dt)\overset{def}{=}F_1(x)\cdot F_2(-\lambda),$$
where I used the definition of distribution in the last step.

Comment: Thank you. Simple enough :).

Comment: glad to be of help :)